# Asp.Net initiate transfer of 2 files with 'Save as' dialog

Tags: asp.net, file, transfer

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "text/txt";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "file.txt");
            Response.Write(@"C:\temp.txt");
            Response.End();
        }
```

Hi, 
the previous code allows me to transfer one file within one click by popping up the 'Save as' dialog box.

I would like to transfer 2 files within on click by popping up 2 'Save as' dialog boxes

I might have a too simplistic approach because the below doesn't work, it just brings one 'Save as' box

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "text/txt";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "file.txt");
            Response.Write(@"C:\temp.txt");
            Response.End();

            Response.ContentType = "text/txt";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "file.txt");
            Response.Write(@"C:\temp.txt");
            Response.End();
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could zip up the 2 files before sending them to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't give more than one response to a request.  You need to work out a way to initiate two requests from the browser.  The first thought that comes to mind is two javascript window.open calls

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to achieve this directly, but you can manage it with a workaround.

Create two `iframes` on your page. Once the user clicks your button, use javascript to change the `src` of the iframes to an aspx page which servers up one file each to be saved.

I haven't tried it, but I think it should work.